# Matlab Writing a matrix to text file issue

Tags: matlab, file, text, matrix

I am trying to correctly display a 25x5 column matrix under its "column headers" (5 of them) into a text-file.

```
fprintf(fileID,'%8s %16s %24s %32s %40s\n', 'ID', 'Column 1', 'Column 2',...
'Column 3', 'Column 4');
fprintf(fileID,'%8.1f %16.1f %24.1f %32.1f %40.1f\n', uData);
```

In the text-file, it is displaying one of the columns across the row like this (e.g. the ID column):

```
ID    Column 1    Column 2   Column 3    Column 4
1            2           3          4           5
```

What it should be doing is going down the "ID" column, as 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 all belong to one column, and I designate that as "ID" in the text file:

```
ID    Column 1    Column 2   Column 3    Column 4
1          ...          ...       ...         ...
2          ...          ...       ...         ...
3          ...          ...       ...         ...
4          ...          ...       ...         ...
```

Note that ... symbolises here that there is data there (the other values in the matrix).

So how may I fix it so that the matrix appears correctly?

Comment: what is uData? Any example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because when you write data using `fprintf` in MATLAB, the data is written in **column-major** format.  That means the values of your matrix are printed to file such that each row of your matrix is actually written in the **columns** instead, which is what you're noticing.  Notice that the values of `1, 2, 3, 4...` are written along the columns first, where you desire the values to be written along the rows.

To write this in row-major (i.e. what you desire), you need to **transpose** your data prior to writing.  Therefore, do this:

```
fprintf(fileID,'%8s %16s %24s %32s %40s\n', 'ID', 'Column 1', 'Column 2',...
'Column 3', 'Column 4');
fprintf(fileID,'%8.1f %16.1f %24.1f %32.1f %40.1f\n', uData.'); %// CHANGE - notice uData
```

Comment: Okay I made use of the transpose function and it worked! Thank you for that suggestion.

Comment: the matrix worked, now I need help putting a cell array data in the first column, and the matrices in the subsequent column (already opened up a question for it).

Comment: @muaaQ - Looks like Divakar has answered your question.  Good luck!